# How to send a dynamic list of objects to controller in MVC using jQuery and Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am populating a form dynamically with objects, allowing a new field to be edited, and then trying to submit the form to another list of a different object type.

I am currently using an Ajax form to do this, but the `<label for=>` attributes are not being sent to the partial view result along with the other attributes.

My controller partial view result is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult AddToOrder(IList<OrderItemModel> form_list)
{ 
    // do something
}
```

The Ajax form in my view is as follows:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddToOrder", "Order", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "result" }))
{
   for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
   {
    <tr>
       <input type="hidden" name="form_list[@i].item_id" value="@Model[i].id" />
       <td><label for="form_list[@i].description">@Model[i].description</label></td>
       <td><label for="form_list[@i].price">@Model[i].price</label></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="form_list[@i].quantity"  value="0" /></td> 
    </tr>
   }

   <td><input type="submit" value="Add to order"/></td>
}
```

If I duplicate my labels as `<input type="hidden">` attributes, all the fields I need are sent to the partial view result, but is there a better way to do this maybe using jQuery instead of an Ajax form?

Comment: I would suggest using Html helpers, that will make everything much more easier and clean.

Answer (score 0):

Labels are never submitted with an HTTP POST.  Only `<input>`, `<select>` and `<textarea>` elements are.

If you want to pass those values back, you can use hidden input fields as you are now doing.